# How do you stop jboss shrinkwrap from resolving dependencies remotely?

Tags: java, maven, build, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am using shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
  <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is alongside Arquillian for testing. When the war is being  built I can see it tries to resolve dependencies remotely which fails due to authentication errors. This fills the logs with warnings from `org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.logging.LogTransferListener`- the war does eventually build and deploy so it must fallback locally.

When running a plain `mvn clean install` the project builds fine which makes me believe it's just a problem with the plugin.

I currently have the below defined which I believe needs to be changed to just look for libraries on my local machines repository.

`File[] file = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importCompileAndRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go to offline mode by invoking

`Maven.configureResolver().workOffline()...`

HTH